# Deleted parent entity if all children were deleted

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and EF. And I have these entities:

```
public class ActionCategory
{
    public short Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Action> Actions { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public short CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public ActionCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

I want to automatically delete `ActionCategory` if all `Actions` were deleted. I understand that I can implement this logic myself but I wonder if there is some EF feature allows to do that. And if there is no such feature could I write a trigger for MySQL database? Wouldn't it be a bad way? I mean split my business logic to controllers and database? Or vice versa it will be a good practice to make this logic on database level?

Comment: There is no standard EF feature for this. You can setup the foreign key with cascade delete but it works in different direction i.e. when `ActionCategory` gets deleted it removes all its `Action` records. As for the trigger I would say that having a trigger is almost always a bad idea because this logic is implicit and is hidden in a database. Somebody may have a hard time to figure out why some of the categories got removed.

Comment: @AlexeyAndrushkevich , agreed with your opinion about triggers but pros of them would be that we can remove the last action without category even by sql request because trigger would catch that anyway. I thought about creating triggers during db initialization on application run. Not complete decision of implicit logic but at least some improvement. What do you think?

Comment: The only good reason for keeping the logic in the database I can think about is having multiple applications talking to the same database. This would help you to provide some data consistency. If you intend to have only one application that inserts and deletes the data then I would keep the logic in the code and try to avoid creating a database trigger. If you still want to use it though - leave the comment in the code saying that trigger is going to fire and remove the `ActionCategory` when last `Action` is removed.

Comment: The regular cascade delete also depends on the database implementing it, in other words, splitting the business logic between client and database already exists, so there should not be a problem of doing that for your quite unusual rule (some sort of a reference counting)

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your replies. I'll think about relevance of trigger creating in my case